# How to pass values from a state to another component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have two pages on my react app. One page allows you to submit a post, and the second page shows all of the posts. I need to be able to retrieve the data from the state on one page, but I am receiving an error. What am I doing wrong to display this, because I thought I could use props to gather the state from my post page.

My Display Post Page:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


export default class Scroll extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (

            <div className="flex-container">
                <div className="post">
                    {this.props.displayPost(this.props.state.posts)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My post page:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import { post } from '../../routes/routes';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        title: "",
        body: "",
        posts: []
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getPost();
    }

    getPost = () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts/save")
            .then((response) => {
                const data = response.data;
                this.setState({ posts: data });
                console.log("Data has been recieved")
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert("Error recieving data")
            })
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;
        const value = target.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    };

    submit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const payload = {
            title: this.state.title,
            body: this.state.body,
        }

        axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/posts/save',
            method: 'POST',
            data: payload,
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Data sent to the server');
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('Internal server error');
            });
    };

    displayPost = (posts) => {
        if (!post.length) return null;

        return posts.map((post, index) => {
            <div key={index}>
                <h3 id="post-text">{post.title}</h3>
                <p id="post-text">{post.body}</p>
            </div>
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("State ", this.state)
        return (
            <div className="flex-container-home">
                <div className="app">
                    <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
                        <input
                            placeholder="title"
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            value={this.state.title}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <textarea placeholder="description"
                            name="body"
                            cols="30" rows="10"
                            value={this.state.body}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        >
                        </textarea>
                        <button>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you displaying your scroll component? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: i have a main.js where i use router to display all the pages

Comment: I don't see any relation between the scroll component and PersonList component as they are on different routes. The props which you are using inside the scroll component only works if there is a parent-child relation between your components(i.e. your scroll component should be rendered inside the personList component) as shown by Modin in the answer below.

Comment: If your components are not related then why not use the 'getPost' method in the scroll component in order to get the data and display it. Why are you taking help of personList component to do that when you can easily do that in scroll component. Also there does not seem to be any relation between these two components.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example:

```
import React from "react";

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    body: "",
    posts: [],
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPost();
  };

  getPost = () => {
    this.setState({ posts: ["post1", "post2", "post3"] });
  };      

  displayPost = (posts) => {
    if (!posts || !posts.length) return null;

    return posts.map((post, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>{post}</p>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Scroll displayPost={this.displayPost} posts={this.state.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Scroll extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="post">
        Posts: {this.props.displayPost(this.props.posts)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a complete beginner at react, so sorry if the answer to this is simple, but I don't understand what you mean when you say to render that component somewhere. In my main App.js I am using a router to switch through the pages, so where would I put the scroll component as you suggested?